# Does character behavior changes difficulty of the game?

Tags: paranoia-happiness-is-mandatory

What are the consequences of having you "Treason Level" and "Status" changed during the game?

Is it something like playing as a "Rogue/troublemaker" versus a "Paladin/good guy" character?

Does it make it easier or harder depending on how you interact with the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your treason level is too high, certain teammates may refuse to follow your orders and leave the team until you visit a confession booth or are terminated.  If your treason level reaches 100%, you will be declared a traitor and asked to report to a termination booth.  If you refuse, IntSec troopers will hunt you down and terminate you.  Good news; your next clone will start over with a clean slate...